# convert data to matrix for a network

Tags: python, r, matrix, networking

I have a large dataset with 30k rows like below:

```
patno    Inentorname 

1001       A
1001       B
1002       A
1002       B
1003       C
1004       D
1004       E
```

What I want to get is like:

```
   A  B  C  D  E 
A  0  2  0  0  0
B  2  0  0  0  0
C  0  0  0  0  0
D  0  0  0  0  1
E  0  0  0  1  0
```

Is there any easy way to get this in R or python?

Comment: @balandongiv [What have you tried? is blocked for a reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming DF shown reproducibly in the Note at the end

```
tab <- crossprod(table(DF))
diag(tab) <- 0
tab
```

giving:

```
           Inentorname
Inentorname A B C D E
          A 0 2 0 0 0
          B 2 0 0 0 0
          C 0 0 0 0 0
          D 0 0 0 0 1
          E 0 0 0 1 0
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
patno    Inentorname 
1001       A
1001       B
1002       A
1002       B
1003       C
1004       D
1004       E"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```